# Get the for "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

When I try to run my code, it show this error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Recipe from './Recipe';
import RecipeSearch from './RecipeSearch';

export default class RecipeList extends Component {
    render() {
        const { recipes } = this.props;
        return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <RecipeSearch />
                    <div className="container my-5" >
                        {/*title*/ }
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-10 mx-auto col-md-6 text-center text-uppercase mb-3">
                                <h1 className="text-slanted">recipe list</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {/*end of title*/}
                        <div className="row">
                            {recipes.map(recipe =>{
                                return <Recipe key={recipe.recipe_id}
                                recipe={recipe}/>;  
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </React.Fragment>
            );
    }
}
```

So how would I fix it?

Comment: Apparently, you're passing in undefined to RecipeList for the `recipes` prop. Instead, pass in an array of recipes. Can't tell you much more without seeing where you're using RecipeList.

Comment: Hi koko, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: First check your props if you are passing it by the correct name or not. Secondly why do use map inside render like that. Create a function for that outside return function and just call that function inside render. This is ideally how you should do it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to your `recipes` props are `undefined`.

You should always check if you are getting data in your `props`,

```
{recipes && recipes.length > 0 && recipes.map(recipe =>{
       return <Recipe key={recipe.recipe_id} recipe={recipe}/>;  
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{recipes && recipes.map(recipe => (
   <Recipe key={recipe.recipe_id} recipe={recipe}/>;
))}
```

You need to check if `recipes` exists first. It's not necessary to check for `recipes.length > 0`, as `[].map()` returns in fact an empty array and is valid:

```js
const A = [1,2,3];
const B = [];

console.log(A.map(x => x*x));
console.log(B.map(x => x*x));
```

If you are using a newer version of react, you don't need to do `<React.Fragment>`, only `<> </>`:

```
<>
  <div> ...
  <span> ...
</>
```

Comment: If that is the concern you should check if `Array.isArray(recipes)` then. What if `recipes` were a string, what would happen?